# Matchlists/tables in power query

Tags: match, string-comparison, powerquery, m

I'm thinking this has to have a simple answer, but I can't find any examples.

I have to compare every member of a list to a list of substrings to see if that member contains a substring, and if it does - return the substring to a third list at the same position as the member of the first list.

Example:

```
ListA = {"help me rhonda",  "in my room", "good vibrations", "god only knows"}
ListB = {"room", "me", "only"}

ListC should then should =  {"me", "room", null, "only"}
```

I'm an advanced programmer who has been writing M for about 4 days now.  It's driving me crazy. I have been trying several different functions, but so far i'm not even close, so I'm not going to list my code.  List.Transform seems the most likely option, but I can't quite work it out.

Thanks for the help,

-J

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Words intersections

```
let
    ListA = {"help me rhonda",  "in my room", "good vibrations", "god only knows"},
    ListB = {"room", "me", "only"},
    intersect=List.Transform(ListA, (lineA)=>Text.Combine(List.Intersect({Text.Split(lineA, " "), ListB}), "|"))
in
    intersect
```

[image]

### Flags only

```
let
    ListA = {"help me rhonda",  "in my room", "good vibrations", "god only knows"},
    ListB = {"room", "me", "only"},
    contains_word=List.Transform(ListA, (lineA)=>List.MatchesAny(ListB, (wordB)=>Text.Contains(lineA, wordB)))
in
    contains_word
```

[image]

Comment: This seems to have answered your question? If so, want to mark it as the answer? If not, let me know and I could take another look. BTW, have you seen the [M quickstart guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt270258.aspx)?